# Domain Admin account unable to access AD server both locally and via RDP

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, windows-server-2019

I am experiencing an issue with our "Primary" domain admin account whereby I am unable to connect to the AD, using this account. I am aware that this is not best practice as we normally use individual admin accounts, however, the domain admin account is only used on exceptional circumstances.

The domain admin account is a member of the following groups:

- Administrators
- Domain Admins
- Enterprise Admins
- Domain Users
- Schema Admins

Among other groups which are not relevant.

There has been no infrastructure change (as far as I am aware of after speaking with my team).

When connecting via RDP, I get the following error:

> *The system administrator has restricted the types of log-on (network or interactive) that you may use. For assistance, contact your system administrator or technical support.*

```
Error code: 0x1307
```

When connecting locally on the server, I get the following error:

> *The sign-in method you're trying to use isn't allowed. For more info, contact your network administrator.*

I have already tried installing the latest updates and restarted the AD server, but still no success.

A potential incident this could be linked back to is an attempt to promote a server in one of our remote sites as a domain controller which failed midway through the process. However, my personal experience with troubleshooting domain controllers is limited, hence why I am reaching out.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Has the administrator account been granted the privilege `deny access to this computer over the network `? This is sometimes done to limit the scope of usage to a 'break glass' account. Should work using the console/IPMI though, which is what nearly all business class hosts have.

Comment: If this is domain wide, double check if you have GPO change that modified User Rights Assignments, logon locally & logon remote. If you still have access to servers in question with other accounts run a gpreuslt /h to see what policy is blocking you

Comment: Yeah, following along with Greg above -- need to revew the User Rights Assignments on the DCs.  Could also be granted the Deny Logon Locally - defintely something I have done for a lot of accounts.

Answer (score 0):

What all the commenters said, especially Greg, but...

Check in Group Policy User Rights Assignment to see if there are any users or groups in the `deny access to this computer over the network` setting. Also check on the server itself and see who is in the Remote Desktop Users allowed under System Properties and insure that the users and groups listed there are what you expect.